# Call event after method is called

Tags: c#, events, delegates

I faced a strange problem actually. I try to create a new Set class based on a Hashset class.

```
public delegate void ChangedEventHandler();
class Set<T> : HashSet<T>
{

    event ChangedEventHandler Added; 

    public bool Add(T item) 
    {
        bool answer = base.Add(item);
        Added?(); //or Added?.Invoke()
        return answer;
    }

}
```

And I want some functions to be executed after Add method is called. Well the above code says that Add was already implemented in base class, but it isn't virtual. I can't override it.

Actually I want to get a result something like this:

```
Set<int> numbers = new Set<int>();
numbers.Added += SumNumbers;
numbers.Added += PrintNumbers;
numbers.Add(2) //Outputs 2
numbers.Add(4) //Outputs 6


//somewhere in this class
public int SumNumbers() {...}
public void PrintNumbers() {...}
```

Frankly speaking, I don't need functions to be with different syntax structure, but there's another question what to do if they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add "new" keyword for method definition, because compiler warns you, that you are hiding base implementation:

```
public new bool Add(T item) 
{
    bool answer = base.Add(item);

    if(Added != null)
    {
        Added();
    }

    return answer;
}
```

Also correct syntax for attaching handlers to event is without "()" (you are passing method, not calling):

```
numbers.Added += SumNumbers;
numbers.Added += PrintNumbers;

//somewhere in this class
public int SumNumbers() {...}
public void PrintNumbers() {...}
```

Comment: This loses its effect as soon as he sticks his collection into a variable of type HashSet. This is not a way to override a method. He'll silently call the wrong method.

Comment: @usr, if I write something like `Set<int> a = new Set<int>()` and add some functions to the event it will lose the effect?

Comment: I am not saying _it is a way of overriding method_. And author never mentiones, that he is using instance through base reference.

Comment: @OlexiyPyvovarov yes. If a method is not virtual you simply cannot make this work. `new` just creates a fresh unrelated method that is misleading.

Comment: No, it won't. Code will work in a way you wrote it untill you will use it through base reference : `HashSet<int> a = new Set<int>()`.

Answer (score 1):

This is normally pattern I use:

```
public class Set<T> : HashSet<T>
{
    private event ChangedEventHandler Added;

    public new bool Add(T item)
    {
        bool answer = base.Add(item);
        OnAdded();
        return answer;
    }

    private void OnAdded()
    {
        if (Added == null)
            return;

        Added();
    }
}
```

Comment: It shows a warning message but still compiles, is that normal?

Comment: Add() is not a virtual method on HashSet<T> so it warns about hiding it.  And it may not function as you want it to.  I would implement a ICollection<T> if I were you.  You could also mark it "new".

Answer (score 0):

If it is not `virtual` and you still want a new implementation for that method add a `"new"` operator to the method to hide the base class implementation like this

```
public new bool Add(T item)
```